# Why can't my electron app access the 'fs' module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, brunch

I have a relatively simple electron app - brunch, react, redux, electron. I'm now trying to read a json file using the "fs" node module, but it's throwing an error:

> TypeError: _fs2.default.readFile is not a function

After investigating it looks like the module doesn't contain anything. Compilation says it's available and bundled, but the resulting vendor.js looks weird. Here's the probably relevant part:

```
[...]
var global = typeof window === 'undefined' ? this : window;require.register("fs", function(exports, require, module) {
  module.exports = {};
});
[...]
```

It doesn't look like brunch correctly bundles these native modules. I also tried it with the electron module and `ipc` but there it already fails upon loading `electron/index.js` when trying to `require('path')`.

Here's my brunch-config.js:

```
exports.files = {
  javascripts: {
    joinTo: {
      'js/vendor.js': /^(?!app)/,
      'js/app.js': /^app/
    }
  },
  stylesheets: {joinTo: 'app.css'}
};

exports.plugins = {
  babel: {
    presets: [
      ['env',
        {
          targets: {
            "browsers": ["Electron >= 1.7.8"]
          }
        }
      ],
      'stage-3',
      'react'
    ]
  }
};
```

Did I forget anything in my brunch config? I'm using ES6 imports, but the problem also happens if I use commonjs.

Comment: What version of `Electron`? If >4 did you set `nodeintergration:true` when you created the window?

Comment: yep:
`mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1024,
        height: 768,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });`